# Какой JS фреймворк посоветуете?

Tags: framework, javascript, angularjs, knockoutjs

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно подоюрать джаваскрипт фреймворк, с которым можно работать на постоянной основе. Главные требования: он должен обязательно быть с двухсторонней привязкой(MVVM), он должен быть достаточно удобный для написания и изучения, желательно чтобы был механизм хэшроутинга и чтобы это легко было реализовать как синглпейдж приложение, удобная подгрузка скриптов, стилей и видов.

Из всего множества более менее знаком с нокаутом и ангуляром, также немного смотрел реакт.

Нокаут впринципе нравится, но хотелось бы иметь хэшроутинг из коробки.

Ангуляр тоже хорош, но с ним достаточно сложно разобраться и как-то не удалось настроить синлпейдж подгрузку скриптов и видов. Хотелось бы почитать что-то основательное, как книжку, а-то по документации ангуляр трудно постичь:)

Реакт хорош своей модульностью, но там как-то очень слабо с двухсторонним связыванием(поправьте, если не прав), да и вообще врядли у него есть более менее приличное комьюнити и плагины.

Если это важно, пишу на asp.net mvc, планирую использовать webapi для выдачи json.

В общем, надеюсь, что кто-то что-то полезное посоветует. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если выбирать между AngularJS и KnockoutJS, то конечно Angular, хотя [Knockout дружит с asp](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template), но это не делает его лучше.

В плане документации и примеров, AngularJS [вне конкуренции](https://www.google.ru/search?q=angularjs+tutorial), чего стоит https://egghead.io/lessons и это всё растет как на дрожжах, сообщество очень большое.

Comment: Только что прочитал про emberjs, что думаете о нем, может ли он конкурировать с ангуляром?

Comment: Они разные, Ember, это такой Backbone на стероидах, всё умеет, но выглядит [очень «сложно»][1].

[1]: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/

Comment: Спасибо за уроки, сижу изучаю, именно этого мне не хватало в ангуляре - какого-то пошагового обучения.

Comment: Эмбер пошел лесом, он весит с джейквери как три ангуляра.

Comment: Предыдущего программиста уволили лишь только за то, что он выбрал вместо Knockout это ваш Англулар. За что и полатился рабочим местом. Такие дела.